# Curl : sending email : getting error :- Warning: Illegally formatted input field

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

code :

```
 attachmentFileWithPath="aa/test.log"
    attachmentType="$(file --mime-type "$attachmentFileWithPath" | sed 's/.*: //')"
     server='smtp.aa.com'
 port='587'
 user='donotreply@gmail.com'
 pass='aaa'
 senderAddress="$user"
 subject="subject"
 mailBody="mail body"

curl --ssl-reqd --url "smtp://$server:$port" \
--user "$user:$pass" \
--mail-from "$senderAddress" \
--mail-rcpt "abc@gmail.com" \
--mail-rcpt "abc1@gmail.com" \
--header "From: donotreply <$senderAddress>" \
--header "To: abc <abc@gmail.com>" \
--header "To: abc1 <abc1@gmail.com>" \
--header "Subject: $subject" \
--form '=(;type=multipart/mixed' --form "=$mailBody;type=text/plain" \
--form "file=@$attachmentFileWithPath;type=$attachmentType;encoder=base64" --form '=)'`
```

Error :

Warning: Illegally formatted input field
curl: option --form: is badly used here

I'm trying to send an email with attachment but getting the above error:

**Note :**  It is working on ubuntu  20.04.4 but not working on ubuntu 16.04.7

Comment: Use `file -b --mime-type` instead of `file --mime-type  | sed...`

Comment: thanks for the comment .. tried the above option but still the same error

Comment: `set -x` to enable trace logging is always a good place to start, so you can compare the arguments you expect to the ones you actually have.

Comment: Could it be that the `curl` version is different between your ubuntu 20 and ubuntu 16 systems? The way you put together your four `--form`  commands looks fishy to me.